# ssh says Network is unreachable although network is reachable

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using ubuntu 20.04.
ssh was working until I rebooted my computer.
Since then I am not able to connect using ssh anymore.

"ssh exemple.com" surprisingly works.
but "ssh 8.8.8.8", or "ssh google.com" outputs "Network is unreachable" and
telnet google.com 22 gives "Network is unreachable" although I can navigate on my browser.

/etc/ssh/ssh_config contains "Port 22"

I already tried all approaches I could found on the internet.
My guess is that ssh request is blocked before reaching the network, but I don't know how to address this problem.

Thanks

Edit : ssh ubuntu@18.198.187.192 -vvv would ask for password, but now shows:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/antoine/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ssh_ant.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ssh_ant.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 18.198.187.192 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 18.198.187.192 [18.198.187.192] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 18.198.187.192 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 18.198.187.192 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I don't think Google is running a public facing SSH server on either of those addresses - so "network unreachable" should be expected as you're being dropped by a firewall. You have to test it with a machine you can actually login to.

Comment: @Panki, utter silence or "connection refused" would make sense, "network unreachable" does not and is not to be expected. Just test it.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I just did with `ssh google.com` and I got `network unreachable`. I think it is difficult for a program to distinguish the exact reason why a connection attempt failed

Comment: I edited my post @EduardoTrápani

Comment: Maybe it's clear, but I don't know if the rebooted machine is the `ssh` client, or the server. Can you ping it? It look like a network issue, more than a `ssh` one.

Comment: The rebooted machine is the client. Indeed, I can not ping the server from my computer (client), so it seems to be a network issue, do you have some ideas in this case?

Comment: 18.198.187.192 looks to be an AWS instance, I have to ask but is this your instance; are you able to verify your instance's IP address hasn't changed?

Comment: @Panki a program does know (via ICMP) whether the network (or host) is unreacheable. A piece of software along the path (a router or firewall) has to trigger it. Otherwise you'd just get a *connection timed out*. You probably have a firewall that "converts" the timeout into *network unreachable*. That depends on the local setup.

Comment: If it is a network problem you might consider closing this question and opening one with the right information. People drawn here to help you with ssh would have to read many comments just to know this is not `ssh` related.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Ok, thank you very much, I will do that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in the comments it is stated that the host is actually NOT reachable, and that was a fact about it. Leaving it open will only waste everybody's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EduardoTrápani Figured out that this was likely a network issue and not an ssh issue as "ping" can not access requested ip addresses either

Comment: @roaima an answer according to EduardoTrápani 's suggestion

Comment: Same for me, I was in a guest network and apparently some ports where blocked